# Is this theorem about "completion of metric space" correct?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

It's well-known that there is a completion of a metric space unique upto isometry.

I have tried to modify this theorem slightly and I proved this statement:

> Let $(X,d_X)$ be a metric space.
>
> Then, there is a unique complete metric space $(Y,d_Y)$ such that $X\subset Y$, $d_Y \upharpoonright (X\times X)= d_X$ and $X$ is dense in $Y$.

This is indeed a yes or no question.. Since I have reformulated the theorem, I want to make sure whether I have proven it correctly.. Is this true?

Comment: even if it is true, the proof maybe wrong though

Comment: This is really just the same question as your previous one, only here you're hiding under the guise of metric spaces rather than hot liquid magma or just plain sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniqueness of $(Y,d_Y)$ in your modified version of the theorem is certainly not true.

Precisely the point of saying that it is *unique up to an isometry* is that instead of $Y$ you can take any set $Y'$ such that there exists a bijection $Y\to Y'$. (And you transfer the metric form  $Y$ to $Y'$ using this bijection; i.e., you take the metric on $Y'$ such that this bijection becomes isometry.)